# Group by data based with same group occuring multiple times

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Input data

id  group

1   a

1   a

1   b

1   b

1   a

1   a

1   a

expected result

id group   row_number

```
1   a   1

1   a   1

1   b   2

1   b   2

1   a   4

1   a   4

1   a   4
```

I require the rwo_number based on the above result. If the same group occurring the second time generates different row_number for that? I have one more column sequence of date top to end.

Comment: Is that sample table data? Show us the expected result as well.

Comment: The first two columns are the input data.Edited the question now make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of a gaps-and-islands problem.  Solving it, though, requires that the data be ordered -- and SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

Let me assume you have such a column.  Then the difference of row numbers can be used:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by id order by grp, (seqnum - seqnum_g)) as grouping
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by ?) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by id, grp order by ?) as seqnum_g
      from t
     ) t;
```

This does not produce the values that you specifically request, but it does identify each group.